# Webpage getting cut on both horizontal and vertical view iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

I am using UIWebview for loading a webpage. All is well on iOS Simulator expect for the following.

- webpage is cut on the RIGHT SIDE for vertical view.
- If I rotate left and see the Horizontal view, BOTTOM part of the webpage is cut.

Height and Width of `UIwebview` are both 600.

It would be really great if you can let me know what has to be done for displaying both VERTICAL and HORIZONTAL Views correctly for any webpage/website.

Comment: Did you add proper constraints to your web view?

Answer (score 0):

Set proper Constraints and

[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];